# How SpringServletContainerInitializer is bootstrapped during Spring initialization?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using WebApplicationInitializer-approach for initialization of Spring's WebApplicationContext. From the official documentation for WebApplicationInitializer:

> Implementations of this SPI will be detected automatically by SpringServletContainerInitializer, which itself is bootstrapped automatically by any Servlet 3.0 container

The question is how SpringServletContainerInitializer is 'bootstrapped automatically'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html)
`SpringServletContainerInitializer` implements `ServletContainerInitializer`.

Implementations of ServletContainerInitializer will be notified by Servlet 3.0-compliant container during container startup. That's a contract of servlet3.0 complaint container.

Doc for `ServletContainerInitializer` can be seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html?is-external=true)

Doc about how its bootstrapped is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html)